# How to color ls - l command's columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wonder if possible to have `ls -l` colored. I'm not talking about `--color`, of course. 
I found an useful alias for display octal permission in an `ls -l` command, now, it's possible to color it? In the same way, is possible when I do `ls -l`, display **only permissions** in red or something?

Comment: `I wonder if possible to have ls -l colored. I'm not talking about --color, of course.` I'm not sure the second sentence is so obvious given the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came into my mind is that you can use `--color=auto` for this:

```
ls -l --color=auto
```

And it can be handy to create an alias:

```
alias lls='ls -l --color=auto'
```

However I see you don't want that. For that we have to create a more complex function that use the `echo -e "colours..."`:

```
print_line () {
        red='\e[0;31m'
        endColor='\e[0m'

        first=${1%% *}
        rest=${1#* }
        echo -e "${red}$first${endColor} $rest"
}

lls () {
        IFS=$'\n'; while read line;
        do
        #       echo "$line"
                print_line $line
        done <<< "$(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%M %p\n')"
}
```

If you store them in `~/.bashrc` and source it (`. ~/.bashrc`) then whenever you do `lls /some/path` it will execute these functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several utilities to do it, like piping the output of `ls (OPTIONS...)` to [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/) (after defiining the rules). Or to [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) (after defining the rules).

Or use awk/sed to pretty print based on regexes. E.g. with `gensub` in awk, you can insert ANSI color codes to the output...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to use color code, but `grep` has `--color` option
If the first line of `ls -l` is not important to you, you can consider using `grep`

```
ls -l | grep --color=always '[d-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-]'
```

or in shorter form:

```
ls -l | grep --color=always '[d-]\([r-][w-][x-]\)\{3\}'
```

Comment: I like it, though you should probably match everything up to space instead, since this will make the file red on the %.0001 chance user has some file matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there is an option to specify custom column-specific colors in [ls](/questions/tagged/ls), I don't think so. But you can do something like.

```
> red() { red='\e[0;31m'; echo -ne "${red}$1  "; tput sgr0; echo "${*:2}"; }
> while read -r line; do red $line; done < <(ls -l)
```

Comment: maybe there's a reason, but for me this looks needlessly complicated. `echo -ne '\e[0;31m'; ls --color=no -l; tput sgr0`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That will make everything red won't it?